# Routing in nextjs, dynamic id not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using the next js routing and using the router.

```
Router.push({
          pathname: this.props.router.pathname,
          asPath: this.props.router.asPath,
          query: { action: "follow" },
        });
```

router.push browser display pathname in next js
http://localhost:3000/mentor/[id]?action=follow

**it should be asPath like**:
http://localhost:3000/mentor/162?action=follow

Answer (score 0):

Add shallow: true

```
Router.push({
      pathname: this.props.router.pathname,
      asPath: this.props.router.asPath,
      query: { action: "follow" },
      { shallow: true }
});
```

[Ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing)